# Make a function of SQL query with optional 'where' clauses

Tags: python, sql

Lets say I have a function that query some table `company.workers`, for example (pseudo code):

```
def sql_query(dept, prof, hireDate):
    q = """SELECT *
            FROM company.workers
            WHERE department = {0} 
            AND profession = {1} 
            AND hire_date > {2}""".format(dept, prof, hireDate)
   cur.execute(q)
   return cur
```

What if I want to allow the user the query only on `dept` and `prof`, with `hireDate` being optional? This is the solution I came up with:

```
def sql_query(dept, prof, *args):
    if args:
        q = """SELECT *
                FROM company.workers
                WHERE department = {0} 
                AND profession = {1} 
                AND hire_date > {2}""".format(dept, prof, args[0])
    else:
        q = """SELECT *
                FROM company.workers
                WHERE department = {0} 
                AND profession = {1} """.format(dept, prof)
    cur.execute(q)
    return cur
#the function could be called as so:
sql_query('20', 'Engineer', (2017-12-10))
```

However I think this is subotimal. What if I want to allow several *optional* coloumns to query? If I make it two, I have 4 options to handle, which is a lot of `else-if` blocks to make. Is there a more efficient/elegant solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL WHERE clause generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496051/dynamic-sql-where-clause-generation).  Also, you really want to look up SQL Injection, or suffer the consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what SQL DBMS you're using, but here's a block of SQL Server-style code that accepts three variables:

```
@dept
@prof
@hireDate
```

The WHERE clause always uses @dept and @prof, and only uses @hireDate if it is not null.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    company.workers
WHERE 
    department = @dept
AND 
    profession = @prof 
AND 
(
    (
        @hireDate IS NOT NULL AND hire_date = @hireDate
        )
OR @hireDate IS NULL
)
```

You could then add as many other option variables as needed using this same style, instead of writing separate SQL statements for each combination.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496051/dynamic-sql-where-clause-generation). You're right, you don't really want to be manually generating the statement. You could improve your current code by making it more dynamic using a dictionary:

```
def sql_query(**params):
    q = "SELECT * FROM company.workers"
    count=0
    for i in non_require_param:
        if count==0:
            q += " WHERE {0} = {1} ".format(i, params[i])
        else:
            q += " AND {0} = {1} ".format(i, params[i])
        count += 1
    cur.execute(q)
    return cur
```

Also,  [sqlite's execute cursor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) is something to look into. It is cleaner than formatting the statement yourself and handles the datatype conversion:

```
who = "Yeltsin"
age = 72
cur.execute("""select * from company.workers 
            where name_last=:name_last and age=:age""",
            {"name_last": who, "age": age})
```